# How to know which element inside UserControl changed the property?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

UserControl contains some CustomControls with "State" property

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="133" d:DesignWidth="175"
         x:Name="my_user_control">    
<Canvas>
    <c:Led State="{Binding SegmentState, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <c:Led State="{Binding SegmentState, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <c:Led State="{Binding SegmentState, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Canvas>
```

SegmentState is a dependency property with PropertyChangedCallback

```
public static DependencyProperty SegmentStateProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("SegmentState", typeof(bool), typeof(MyUserControl),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(SegmentStateChanged)));
```

But inside SegmentStateChanged I cannot find which one the Leds changed the property. Is there any way to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SegmentState` is going to be `bool`, you should write three `SegmentState` properties and bind each `c:Led` control's `State` property to a different one:

```
<c:Led State="{Binding Segment0State, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<c:Led State="{Binding Segment1State, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<c:Led State="{Binding Segment2State, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

If the number of segments is not fixed, you could instead write a trivial `SegmentState` class which just has a `bool Value` property, have a collection of instances called `SegmentStates`, and bind to items in that collection -- but then you have to write some code to respond to changes in the `Value` properties. The approach above involves a little copy'n'paste but it's by far the easiest to get working correctly.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SegmentStates}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <c:Led State="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```